# Wrapping character "Y" in span, increases the margin to next character

Tags: html, css

In my current project, I need to wrap every single character of a sentence within a span, so I can measure the distance from the beginning of the sentence up until the character in question.

Unfortunately, it seems that wrapping *some* of the characters (I found it to be true for "Y" and "T") in a span, adds an extra margin to the right, so the whole text gets stretched:

```css
div { font-size: 100px; }
```

```html
<h2>Expected (same width):</h2>
<div>A-A-A-A</div>
<div>
  <span>A</span><span>-</span><span>A</span><span>-</span><span>A</span><span>-</span><span>A</span>
</div>

<h2>Unexpected (different width):</h2>
<div>Y-Y-Y-Y</div>
<div>
  <span>Y</span><span>-</span><span>Y</span><span>-</span><span>Y</span><span>-</span><span>Y</span>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet, you will realize, that "Y-Y-Y-Y" is significantly wider when wrapped in SPANs.

Why is that so? How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: This happens in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had tried it only in Chrome before. Could not experience this with FF.

Answer (score 7):

You can solve that with setting `font-kerning:none;` to the `div`

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/m52yo6y0/2/)

```
div { font-size: 100px; font-kerning: none; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning

Comment: I'm looking at your fiddle in Chrome v49.0.2623.110 (64-bit) and the problem is still there - [preview](http://s23.postimg.org/lnzi6hriz/Screen_Shot_2016_04_11_at_14_46_01.png). Can this be a chrome bug?

Comment: It should be good according to this link :  http://caniuse.com/#search=font-kerning
Besides, I'm testing with the almost same setting as you (Chrome v49.0.2623.112) and it works so I don't know what to say :/

Comment: Interesting... maybe it's due the OS? I'm on OSX el capitan.

Comment: Could be that indeed : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning#Kerning_tables
I'm on Windows ;)
Maybe try with that property too : `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`

Answer (score 2):

Whether this happens seems to depend on your browser's default font. Some fonts may have kerning (letter spacing adjustments) that reduces the space between a capital `Y` and a short letter or dash.

It seems that Chrome's text rendering engine either uses more kerning than other browsers, or fails to apply it when there's a html tag between the letters.

You can resolve this issue by giving your `div` a specified font-family:

```
div {
    font-family: Courier New;
}
```

(does not have to be a monospace font, but those are guaranteed to not have kerning)

Comment: But then what does it have to with it being wrapped in a span ?

Comment: My project's default font is Arial => kerning applies

Answer (score 0):

Any mono-spaced font may help as each character is the same width.

You could also try this:
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/characterletter-widths-in-css/